# What are the available /systemTopic/ channels in the Streaming API?

Tags: streaming-api, pushtopic

There appear to be at least two Streaming API channels that don't require a PushTopic to be created.

1. `/systemTopic/Logging` for ApexLog from [Using the ApexCSIAPI that backs to Force.com Console to pull data](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/20896/102)
2. `/systemTopic/TestResult` for ApexTestResult from [ApexTestQueueItem](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_apextestqueueitem.htm)

Are there any others? I can't find any documentation about what other systemTopics are available.

Answer (score 1):

It would appear the system topics aren't intentionally published as they are considered for internal use only. Oddly, the TestResult topic is part of the Salesforce published documentation.

> [@FishOfPrey](https://twitter.com/FishOfPrey) system topics
>   are generic streaming channels meant to be used by internal services.
>   What is use-case to have/see all? [@gwestr](https://twitter.com/gwestr)
>   — John Brock
>   (@_johnbrock) [November 25, 2014](https://twitter.com/_johnbrock/status/537040065487060992)

I did however find some additional system topics by checking for POSTs to `/cometd` in the Chome Developer tools when the Salesforce Developer Console was open.

1. `/systemTopic/ContainerDeployStateChange`
2. `/systemTopic/ApexExecutionOverlayResult`

Answer (score 1):

`/systemTopic/Logging` seeems to be used by the new sfdx command `sfdx force:apex:log:tail`

Comment: The Streaming API would be an odd way to get the latest debug log from a command line tool. I thought they just went straight to the most recent ApexLog with the REST Tooling API.

Comment: Yep it is using ApexLog from tooling API to retrieve log details, but notification of new executions come from this stream. Similarly with test results - it listens for TestResult event and then queries ApexTestResult and ApexTestRunResult. You can inspect code yourself at `~/.local/share/sfdx/client/node_modules/salesforce-alm/`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a couple more from [Salesforce DX Apex Debugging license issue](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/214760/salesforce-dx-apex-debugging-license-issue):

-Connected to Streaming API channel /systemTopic/ApexDebuggerSystemEvent.

-Connected to Streaming API channel /systemTopic/ApexDebuggerEvent.

I'm trying to figure out how to play around with /systemTopic/Logging.  Can I just substitute it in place of /u/notification/someChannel in a subscriber I set up?

Comment: I use `/systemTopic/Logging` directly against the streaming API. The only catch so far has been to pin it to API version 36.0. If you watch the developer console network traffic it is doing the same thing.

Comment: I posted a question about how I was trying, https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/265257/accessing-systemtopic-streaming-channel