# Issues displaying logs in Developer Console? Possibly Summer 15 related

Tags: developer-console, logging, summer-15

I tend to keep a Developer Console open when testing code, so that I can get debug logs automatically for my session.  Today I am finding that when I open the console I do see logs appear, but after a while I stop getting them.  It's not long enough for the console session to have timed out (maybe 10 minutes, sometimes less), and the Debug menu does not give the "Resume Updates" option.  This is even happening when running anonymous apex code; after a few executions, it stops showing the logs.  Closing and re-opening will start it capturing logs again.

I just realized that this sandbox was upgraded to Summer '15 this past weekend.  Is anyone else having issues with logs being listed in the Developer Console?

**edit:** To be clear, I can click on a listed log and see it without issue.  The issue is that after a brief interval, new logs stop appearing in the log panel.

Comment: Try double checking the [TraceFlag](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_tooling/Content/sforce_api_objects_traceflag.htm) expiration for the current user. You can see this under "Change Log Levels" in the developer console. The Expiration should be green.

Comment: Or try the following SOQL against the Tooling API. `Select Id, ExpirationDate, ScopeId, TracedEntityId from TraceFlag`. The ScopeId and TracedEntityId should be your UserId. The UTC ExpirationDate should be in the future.

Comment: @DanielBallinger After several days of not observing this issue, it is occurring again.  I checked the TraceFlag expiration via Developer Console's "Change Log Levels" dialog, and it was about a half hour in the future; I ran the Tooling API query and got the same result (as expected).  Thinking that checking it may have reset it, I retried my VF page as well as an anonymous apex request via the Developer Console, and no new logs appeared in the Console's Logs tab. Closing and re-opening allows the logs to begin appearing again.  No issues on trust.salesforce.com for this instance (cs15).

Comment: If the TraceFlag records look good and restarting the developer console fixes the issue I'd be looking at the streaming API as the problem. The developer console uses the `/systemTopic/Logging` topic to monitor the debug logs [See Related](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/57107/102). Try a SOQL query against [ApexLog](https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_apexlog.htm).

Comment: I have observed this same behavior with a Summer 15 org and it is VERY annoying. Hope to see a fix soon.

Comment: Just curious, but Jason, what OS and browser are you using? I am getting this with Windows and the latest version of Chrome

Comment: @SaraMorgan Latest Chrome on OS X Yosemite

Comment: @JasonClark I've been seeing this too, I've been able to get things working by changing the expiration date on the current trace via debug->change log levels. If it's a critical log, i'll check that I get a log for an execute anonymous statement, if I still don't get a log I'll refresh the dev console. Can't find a pattern

Comment: This is driving me crazy.  Every 10 or so debug logs i get I have to change my log levels.   Salesforce needs to address this ASAP!!!

Answer (score 3):

I have also been experiencing this. Here are the steps that I have taken to 'fix it' quotes are because the fix seems to expire... sigh!

In the dev console debug ==> change log levels set the monitoring level on the classes you want to track in the log and set the expiration time to be in the future. The red ones are expiring so you want them to be green.

Also in the dev console, uncheck show my current logs only.

Through the Salesforce UI add yourself to the monitored users.
Also in the SF UI under develop==> test execution ==> options uncheck store only aggregated code coverage.

These steps got me close to being able to monitor the logs as before... Good luck!