# Salesforce DX Apex Debugging license issue

Tags: salesforcedx, vs-code, apex-debugger

I'm trying to get Apex debugging working in VS Code, following instructions [here](https://github.com/forcedotcom/salesforcedx-vscode/tree/develop/packages/salesforcedx-vscode-apex-debugger#prerequisites). When I launch the debugger I see a popup `You exceeded your licensed number of debugging sessions. Please end other sessions or purchase more.` even though I believe I have a license and there are no other debugging sessions.

The debug console shows:

```
Connected to Streaming API channel /systemTopic/ApexDebuggerSystemEvent.
Connected to Streaming API channel /systemTopic/ApexDebuggerEvent.
Disconnected from Streaming API channel /systemTopic/ApexDebuggerSystemEvent.
Disconnected from Streaming API channel /systemTopic/ApexDebuggerEvent.
```

My scratch org states `Your org doesn't have any active Apex Debugger sessions` and my DevHub is a production org and states `Your child orgs aren't using any Apex Debugger licenses. You have 1 license available.`

What am I missing? Is there anything I can do to debug this issue further?

Answer (score 3):

You need to enable debugging in the scratch org by adding the "DebugApex" option to the "features" attribute of the scratch org definition file:

```
{
  "orgName": "Acme",
  "country": "US",
  "edition": "Enterprise",
  "description": "Scratch Org Name",
  "hasSampleData": "true",
  "features": ["DebugApex", "AuthorApex"],
  "orgPreferences": {
    "enabled": ["S1DesktopEnabled", "ChatterEnabled"],
    "disabled": []
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I already had the DebugApex feature in my scratch org def. I actually didn't have AuthorApex but, having now added it, I'm still getting the license error when debugging. I also have the PermissionSet created as per the debugger setup instructions, and assigned to the default sysadmin user. Without the permission assignment I see a permission error whilst debugging so seems like it's getting that far at least.